# REST web service Basic authentication + Client Facebook app authentication = double authentication?

Tags: facebook, web-services, rest, basic-authentication

1. I have built a web service based on a REST design. Of course some of the operations available on resources require authentication (delete a user for example). I use Basic authentication and so far everything is fine.
2. I have built a client to consume the web service : a set of Ajax function. Again, everything is fine (also for the Basic authentication).
3. I want now to create a whole web app that will use the set of Ajax function above to interact with the web service. But, to enhance the user experience, some of the web app functions will require Facebook authentication.

So here is my problem. The web app will require username and password to call the web service via the Basic authentication. But it will also require Facebook credentials to use Facebook API and the user will have to log in twice. Moreover, every time I will have to check if the Facebook user (currently logged in Facebook) corresponds to the user of the web service and it is quite troublesome.

Does anyone have an idea to simplify the process ?

It's a bit related to that post [authentication-scheme-for-multi-tiered-web-application-utilizing-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462863/authentication-scheme-for-multi-tiered-web-application-utilizing-rest-api/6463357#6463357) but I did not find any answer I could understand.

Comment: Do you must use the basic authentication in this scenario? Can't you use the facebook login instead?

Comment: I would say yes : you'll have more information on the first comment I made for the Jakub Przyborowski answer

Answer (score 4):

In such scenarios, I use only Facebook authentication. If user is logged into Facebook by JS SDK, you can simply get accessToken by FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken. Then, you can pass it into webservice and use it to authenticate on server side.

First, client side authentication with JS SDK:

```js
/* assumed, that you alredy called FB.login() and stuff */
var accessToken = FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken;
$.ajax({
    'url' : 'rest.php',
    'type' : 'get',
    'dataType' : 'json',
    'data' : { accessToken : accessToken },
    'success' : function(response) {
        /* some fancy code, blah blah blah */
    }
});
```

I use PHP SDK, so I'll show example in PHP.

```php
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$accessToken = $_GET['accessToken'];
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxx'
));     
$facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken);

if ($facebook->getUser()) {
    // yaay, user is authenticated
    echo json_encode($mySuperDuperSecretContentForLoggedUserOnly);
} else {
    // authentication failed
    echo json_encode(null);
}
```

Comment: Actually, my web service may have different client applications. And some of them will not use Facebook, I want all the stuff dealing with Facebook done on the client side (ok, the server can still store facebook id of a given user but that's all), and not all the users will use Facebook. So I am constrained by Basic authentication for the web service called. Thank you anyway !

Comment: In such case I suggest to unify authentication methods. You can switch from basic auth to token based authentication and use universal access token same way like facebook does. If user uses facebook login - you pass facebook access token. If not - you generate your own token on login and then use it the same way as facebook access token.

Answer (score 0):

If your main design uses basic authentication, but you want on some cases to be able to connect with facebook, then I suggest that you use an adapter/bridge on your server that will be able to take the facebook auth data and then handle the basic authentication itself.

That way the facebook users won't have to go through 2 authentication processes, and you don't break anything in your original flow.

It should not be hard to implement, when a user signs up just associate his fb account with a user in your system, then when he logs in with facebook take his id and log him into the system using the basic authentication.

One thing though, if you want to implement the facebook authentication using client side then you should send the auth data in https.